# return command from a newbie in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying out the return function for the first time. The following lines of code show no output. I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. I'd appreciate your input.

```
def favourite_drink name
   if name == "tea"
     return "I love tea too!"
   end

   if name == "lemonade"
     return "Stuff's refreshing, isn't it?"
   end

   if name == "coffee"
     return "Dude, don't have too much of that stuff!"
   end

   "So what exactly is it that you like? (scratches head)"
end  

favourite_drink "tea"
```

Comment: Please take a look at the available formatting options, especially the code-button (`{}`) next time. It helps to make your code more readable :D

Answer (score 2):

There's no output because you don't output the result of your function.

```
puts favourite_drink("tea")
```

outputs:

```
"I love tea too!"
```

You've probably experimented with Ruby in `irb`, which is a REPL -- a read-eval-print loop.  In irb, if you entered your code, you'd see:

```
 => "I love tea too!"
```

because `irb` automatically shows you the value of whatever you type.  When actually running your program, you need to specifically ask to output whatever you want printed.

Comment: This can be confusing if you have been working in the console/irb, where it automatically prints the value of expressions that you type.

Comment: @benzado I had the same thought -- I was elaborating my answer at the same time you were commenting. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Ruby wizz by far, but I think you are missing a piece of code that will actually do the  output for you. You have some strings, but they remain just that: string. To actually send them to the screen you need a command like `puts` or `print`.

see: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings

```
puts 'Hello world'
```

Answer (score 1):

To target your method, in order to display out the string "I love tea too!" to the output screen(your terminal) you need to give accurate instructions to your method. i.e, you need to instruct your method 'favourite_drink' to take the argument "tea" and paly with it according to the structure described inside the method 'favourite_drink'

> puts favourite_drink "tea"

the above will solve your issue.

Comment: or like Nanne puts it succinctly